# Find $\int\frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$

Tags: integration

$\int\frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$

I tried solving it but could not finish.I tried putting $e^x=t$ but not getting integrable.Please help me in solving it.

Comment: I don't think it is integrable.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration+of+%28x%5E2%2Bx%29%2F%28e%5Ex%2Bx%2B1%29%5E2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given, $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx = \int\frac{(e^x+x+1)x-xe^x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx $

$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{x}{e^x+x+1}dx-\int\frac{xe^x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$

$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{(e^x+x+1)-(e^x+1)}{e^x+x+1}dx-\int\frac{(xe^{-x})}{(1+xe^{-x}+e^{-x})^2}dx$

Now in second integral put $(1+xe^{-x}+e^{-x}) = t\;,$ then $\left(-xe^{-x}+e^{-x}-e^{-x}\right)dx = dt$, $\implies -xe^{-x}dx =dt$.

$\displaystyle I  = x-\ln|e^x+x+1|-\frac{1}{1+xe^{-x}+e^{-x}}+\mathcal{C}$

Comment: $a^2 (b + c + d)^2 \neq (ab + ac + ad)^2$. The expression for the second integral is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$I=\int\dfrac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx=\dfrac{xe^{-x}\cdot(x+1)e^{-x}}{\{1+e^{-x}(x+1)\}^2}dx$$

Let $1+e^{-x}(x+1)=u\implies-xe^{-x}dx=du$

$$I=\int\dfrac{u-1}{u^2}du$$

Hope the rest should not be too tough!

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\int\frac{x(x+1)}{(1+e^x+x)^2}dx&=\int\frac{(1+e^x+x)^2-(1+e^x)(1+e^x+x)-xe^x}{(1+e^x+x)^2}dx\\
&=\int1dx-\int\frac{1+e^x}{(1+e^x+x)}dx-\int\frac{xe^x}{(1+e^x+x)^2}dx\\
\end{align}